# Differentiate two on Activity Results by Request Code, How to write Request Code for "loginWIthFB" in the code

Tags: android, onactivityresult

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoginSocial.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Updates.OnFragmentInteractionListener,View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private SignInButton sign;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    static final int Set_Ringtone = 0;
    static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private String TAG;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeControls();
        loginWithFB();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        sign = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        sign.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())

        {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                sign();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sign() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }



    private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }


    }

    private void updateUI(boolean b) {


    }





    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new LoginSocial(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new Updates(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }



    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


    TextView txtStatus;
    LoginButton fb_login;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;



    private void initializeControls(){

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        txtStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        fb_login = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login);
    }


    private void loginWithFB(){

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                txtStatus.setText("Login Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                txtStatus.setText("Login Cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                txtStatus.setText("Login Error:"+error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleResult(result);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FacebookSdk.isFacebookRequestCode()` to check if the request code is from Facebook.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (FacebookSdk.isFacebookRequestCode(requestCode) {
        // Facebook
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
       // Google
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am unable to open my app in Emulator. I feel there is a problem with Tablayout. I have tried the code without Tablayout and it worked. But in Tablayout its not opening. Please help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you post a new question as this is a different problem to the original question. Make sure you include the error log to make it easier to identify the problem. I will try my best to help.

Comment: Thank You. I have posted my question on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000222/unable-to-open-the-app-in-emulator-due-to-tablayout-i-guess?noredirect=1#comment76974676_45000222. Thank you very much