# Application Not running on Emulator due to “Binder Thread Pool”

Tags: android, build, android-emulator

10-07 00:23:49.443 1268-1268/? E/hwservicemanager: BINDER_SET_INHERIT_FIFO_PRIO failed with error -1

```
                                               --------- beginning of system
```

10-07 00:23:51.504 1268-1268/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 1871 ms
10-07 00:23:55.324 1271-1280/? E/vold: Failed to pclose /system/bin/sgdisk --android-dump /dev/block/vold/disk:253,48 : Success
10-07 00:23:55.947 1271-1280/? E/vold: Failed to pclose /system/bin/blkid -c /dev/null -s TYPE -s UUID -s LABEL /dev/block/vold/disk:253,48 : Success
10-07 00:24:00.318 1331-1348/? E/adbd: Could not start mdnsd.
10-07 00:24:00.541 1314-1314/? E/Netd: cannot find interface dummy0
10-07 00:24:00.544 1314-1314/? E/Netd: Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
10-07 00:24:01.528 1321-1321/? E/hwcomposer: unknown display attribute 6
10-07 00:24:02.638 1328-1328/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
10-07 00:24:03.322 1331-1348/? E/adbd: Could not register mDNS service (-65563).
10-07 00:24:08.112 1320-1320/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 377 ms

```
                                                [ 10-07 00:24:08.400  1328: 1328 D/         ]
                                                SurfaceInterface::setAsyncMode: set async mode 1
```

10-07 00:24:18.899 1318-1318/? E/SoundTriggerHalImpl: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:24:19.158 1333-1333/? E/EmulatedCamera_Factory: 2 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
10-07 00:24:19.159 1333-1333/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.0', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
10-07 00:24:19.159 1333-1333/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.1', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
10-07 00:24:19.162 1333-1333/? E/CamProvider@2.4-impl: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
10-07 00:24:19.162 1333-1333/? E/CamProvider@2.4-impl: initialize: Vendor tag setup failed, will not be available.
10-07 00:24:19.382 1333-1333/? E/CameraService: onDeviceStatusChanged: State transition to the same status 0x1 not allowed
10-07 00:24:19.383 1333-1333/? E/CameraService: onDeviceStatusChanged: State transition to the same status 0x1 not allowed
10-07 00:24:19.541 1318-1499/? E/BroadcastRadio: couldn't load radio module radio.fm (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:24:19.541 1332-1332/? E/RadioService: could not read implementation properties
10-07 00:24:19.545 1332-1332/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: could not read implementation properties
10-07 00:24:20.450 1328-1427/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-07 00:24:20.459 1457-1524/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
10-07 00:24:28.276 1457-1540/? E/BootAnimation: Could not add watch for /data/system
10-07 00:25:07.276 1315-1315/? E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: activity_recognition HAL is deprecated. class_init is effectively a no-op
10-07 00:25:37.853 1315-1315/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
10-07 00:25:37.922 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.922 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-bg.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-bn.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-cu.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-cy.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-da.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1901.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1996.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-ch-1901.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-gb.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-es.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-et.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-fr.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.923 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-ga.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-gu.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hi.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hr.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hu.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hy.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-kn.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-ml.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-mn-cyrl.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-mr.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nb.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.924 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-or.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-pa.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-pt.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sl.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-ta.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-te.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-tk.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:37.925 1315-1315/? E/Hyphenator: hyphenation patterns for /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.hyb not found or unreadable
10-07 00:25:41.694 1681-1681/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
10-07 00:25:42.147 1328-1427/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-07 00:25:42.149 1681-1709/system_process E/LocalDisplayAdapter: Default and active color mode is no longer available! Reverting to first available mode.
10-07 00:25:42.204 1681-1709/system_process E/LightsService: Unable to get ILight interface.
10-07 00:25:45.663 1681-1681/system_process E/PackageManager: There should probably be a verifier, but, none were found
10-07 00:25:46.057 1681-1744/system_process E/SensorService: Reported power 0.000000 not deemed sane, clamping to 0.001000

```
                                                         [ 10-07 00:25:46.064  1681: 1744 E/         ]
                                                         Reporting Mode incorrect: sensor Goldfish Temperature sensor handle=0x00000003 type=13 actual=0 expected=1

                                                         [ 10-07 00:25:46.064  1681: 1744 E/         ]
                                                         Reporting Mode incorrect: sensor Goldfish Humidity sensor handle=0x00000007 type=12 actual=0 expected=1
```

10-07 00:25:46.487 1681-1698/system_process E/SystemServer: Unable to preload default resources
10-07 00:25:48.729 1681-1764/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
10-07 00:25:48.820 1681-1764/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
10-07 00:25:48.908 1681-1699/system_process E/AppIdleHistory: Unable to read app idle file for user 0
10-07 00:25:50.365 1681-1776/system_process E/WificondControl: Failed to get reference to wificond
10-07 00:25:50.365 1681-1776/system_process E/WifiNative-wlan0: Failed to teardown interfaces from Wificond
10-07 00:25:50.374 1681-1681/system_process E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Can't call setDebugParams, ISupplicant is null
10-07 00:25:51.044 1681-1681/system_process E/HardwarePropertiesManagerService-JNI: Unable to get Thermal service.
10-07 00:25:51.234 1681-1681/system_process E/ContextHubService: Could not load context hub hal
10-07 00:25:51.304 1353-1353/? E/FingerprintHal: Could not load fingerprints from storage at /data/system/users/0/fpdata/emufp.bin; it has not yet been created.
10-07 00:25:51.726 1681-1681/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:25:51.727 1681-1681/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:25:51.727 1681-1681/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:25:51.727 1681-1681/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:25:51.727 1681-1681/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:25:52.382 1681-1681/system_process E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/0/wallpaper_orig (No such file or directory)
10-07 00:25:52.383 1681-1681/system_process E/WallpaperManagerService: Unable to apply new wallpaper
10-07 00:25:52.414 1271-1281/? E/vold: Failed to pclose /system/bin/sgdisk --android-dump /dev/block/vold/disk:253,48 : Success
10-07 00:25:52.426 1681-1789/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
10-07 00:25:52.442 1681-1776/system_process E/HalDeviceManager: getAllChipInfo: called but mWifi is null!?
10-07 00:25:52.442 1681-1776/system_process E/HalDeviceManager: getSupportedIfaceTypesInternal: no chip info found
10-07 00:25:52.465 1271-1281/? E/vold: Failed to pclose /system/bin/blkid -c /dev/null -s TYPE -s UUID -s LABEL /dev/block/vold/disk:253,48 : Success
10-07 00:25:52.471 1681-1703/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
10-07 00:25:52.472 1681-1703/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
10-07 00:25:52.740 1271-1281/? E/vold: Failed to pclose /system/bin/blkid -c /dev/null -s TYPE -s UUID -s LABEL /dev/block/vold/public:253,48 : No such file or directory
10-07 00:25:52.740 1271-1281/? E/vold: public:253,48 unsupported filesystem 
10-07 00:25:52.839 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionXtra GnssXtra interface not implemented by HAL
10-07 00:25:52.839 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionAGnssRil GnssRil interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.839 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionAGnss AGnss interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.840 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssNavigationMessage GnssNavigationMessage interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.841 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssMeasurement GnssMeasurement interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.842 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssDebug: GnssDebug interface is not implemented by HAL
10-07 00:25:52.843 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssNi GnssNi interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.843 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssConfiguration GnssConfiguration interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.844 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssGeofencing GnssGeofencing interface not implemented by GNSS HAL
10-07 00:25:52.844 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnss flp hw_get_module failed: -2
10-07 00:25:52.844 1342-1342/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssBatching: GnssBatching interface is not implemented by HAL
10-07 00:25:52.856 1681-1681/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Xtra interface
10-07 00:25:52.857 1681-1681/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to Initialize AGnss interface
10-07 00:25:52.857 1681-1681/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Geofencing interface
10-07 00:25:52.857 1681-1681/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS NI interface
10-07 00:25:53.028 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
10-07 00:25:53.036 1681-1681/system_process E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: activity_recognition HAL is deprecated. is_supported is effectively a no-op
10-07 00:25:53.094 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Xtra interface
10-07 00:25:53.094 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to Initialize AGnss interface
10-07 00:25:53.094 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Geofencing interface
10-07 00:25:53.094 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS NI interface
10-07 00:25:53.094 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
10-07 00:25:53.095 1681-1699/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Failed to initialize GNSS batching
10-07 00:25:54.850 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a0fc0:google.mpeg4.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:54.850 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a0fc0:google.mpeg4.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:54.860 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1380:google.h263.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:54.860 1343-1438/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1380:google.h263.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:54.876 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1140:google.h264.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:54.876 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1140:google.h264.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:54.952 1681-1681/system_process E/SystemServerTiming: SystemServer init took too long. uptimeMillis=141952
10-07 00:25:55.229 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1380:google.hevc.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:55.229 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1380:google.hevc.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:55.329 1320-1320/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 134 ms
10-07 00:25:55.495 1328-1328/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1328: eglCreateSyncKHR(1884): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
10-07 00:25:55.686 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a0fc0:google.vp8.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:55.686 1343-1438/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a0fc0:google.vp8.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:55.693 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1140:google.vp9.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:55.693 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xa94a1140:google.vp9.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
10-07 00:25:56.013 1343-1438/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a1320:google.h263.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:56.486 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a13e0:google.mpeg4.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:56.717 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a1320:google.vp8.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:56.734 1343-1438/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a1140:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:57.354 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a11a0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:57.931 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a1440:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:58.256 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a12c0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:58.421 1343-1438/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a1680:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:58.582 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a0fc0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:58.617 1801-2006/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for user_dictionary
10-07 00:25:58.876 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a12c0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:59.079 1343-1439/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a10e0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-07 00:25:59.083 1328-1427/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-07 00:25:59.304 1343-1910/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xa94a1680:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)

```
                                              [ 10-07 00:25:59.308  1932: 2024 D/         ]
                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa7afb940, tid 2024
```

10-07 00:25:59.430 1320-1320/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 121 ms

```
                                                [ 10-07 00:25:59.430  1328: 1659 D/         ]
                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaff5e940, tid 1659
```

10-07 00:25:59.697 1320-1320/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 131 ms
10-07 00:26:00.009 1681-1681/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
10-07 00:26:00.204 1681-1681/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
10-07 00:26:00.308 1344-1344/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 228 ms
10-07 00:26:00.580 1681-1681/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
10-07 00:26:01.375 1328-1428/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer (BlackSurface#2) in layer parent (no-parent).
10-07 00:26:03.208 1681-1681/system_process E/WiredAccessoryManager: No state change.
10-07 00:26:03.238 1870-2066/com.android.phone E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
10-07 00:26:03.711 1870-1870/com.android.phone E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
10-07 00:26:04.123 1681-1788/system_process E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device offline

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion?

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried.... But not getting resolved

Answer (score 0):

In Build gradle(Project).Just add this line

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

It will work.